# Как пройтись по коллекции и присваивать элемент этой коллекции в переменную?

Tags: c#, blazor

У меня есть база данных с командами.
Я записываю все эти команды в коллекцию:

```
private IEnumerable<BashData> _allCommands = new List<BashData>();
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    _allCommands = repository.GetAllCommands();
}
```

Теперь мне необходимо проходиться по этой коллекции с помощью стрелок, а промежуточные результаты выводить в поле, к которому привязана переменная. Вот мой html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Bash command" aria-label="Bash command"
               aria-describedby="basic-addon2" @bind="_bashCommand" @onkeydown="OnKeyDown">
```

А вот код метода **OnKeyDown**:

```
private void OnKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Key == "ArrowUp")
     {
          _bashCommand = 
     }
     else if (e.Key == "ArrowDown")
     {
          _bashCommand = 
     }
 }
```

Допустим, в коллекции есть: *"help", "test", "git help", "git"*. По нажатию на стрелочку, в поле попадает команда *help*. *Если еще раз нажать на стрелочку, то в поле должна появится команда* *test*.
**Если обратиться к псевдокоду, то это будет так:**

```
if(e.Key == "ArrowUp"){
  _bashCommand = _allCommands.MoveNext();
}
if(e.Key == "ArrowDown"{
  _bashCommand = _allCommands.MoveBack();
}
```

**Все должно работать, как в cmd, где мы можем переключать введенные команды с помощью стрелочек**.

//Изменил код

Я решил использовать List:

```
private List<string> _allCommands = new List<string>();
```

А вот обработчик нажатия на кнопки:

```
bool isEdit = true;
    int index = 0;
    void KeyHandler(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == "ArrowUp")
        {
            if (!isEdit)
            {
                isEdit = true;
                index = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                index++;
                if (index > _allCommands.Count() - 1) index = a.Count() - 1;
            }

            _bashCommand = _allCommands[index];
        }
        else if (e.Key == "ArrowDown")
        {
            if (!isEdit)
            {
                isEdit = true;
                index = _allCommands.Count() - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                index--;
                if (index < 0) index = 0;
            }
            _bashCommand = _allCommands[index];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ну так может использовать список или массив вместо `IEnumerable<BashData>` и хранить где то индекс текущей команды?

Comment: Да, вы правы, я дополнил вопрос. Теперь мне нужно как-то сохранять всю историю команд в базе данных

Comment: Ну это уже совершенно другой вопрос, разве нет?